# Using a play button ('Click Me') over default video poster not working

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video . I have placed a text "Click Me" at the center of the video.

My requirement is - on clicking on the "Click Me" or any part of the video , the video should play and "Click Me" disappear.

```
.banner-description{
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    top : 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: rebeccapurple;
}
.video-banner{
    position: relative;
}


<body>

    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis laudantium nobis laboriosam quaerat. Quo, veritatis harum nemo eligendi sed dicta fugiat ad. Voluptas ea maxime qui nostrum blanditiis facere natus!
    </div>

    <div class="video-banner">
        <video controls>
            <source src="011-video-files.mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="banner-description">
            <p>Click Me</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde explicabo repellat minima magnam totam, temporibus nemo saepe praesentium ipsam a quidem. Mollitia vero impedit architecto quod ex voluptates neque eveniet!
    </div>



</body>
```

The problem is : while clicking on the "Click Me" , nothing happens . And , while clicking on some other part of the video, though video starts "Click Me" dose not disappear

Comment: You have not written code to handle the onclick.

Comment: could you please show me , a sample code example for this scenario

Comment: You have to do google for this as it is very basic.

Answer (score 1):

Add `(click)` event to `.video-banner` and to the `video` and `play()` the video in function...

Also add class to `click me` onclick to hid it as `[ngClass]="{'hide': isClicked}"`

[Here is working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-yx96ma?file=src/app/app.component.css)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis laudantium nobis laboriosam quaerat. Quo, veritatis harum nemo eligendi sed dicta fugiat ad. Voluptas ea maxime qui nostrum blanditiis facere natus!
</div>

<div class="video-banner" (click)="play()">
    <video controls #videoPlayer>
        <source src="011-video-files.mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="banner-description" (click)="play()" [ngClass]="{'hide': isClicked}">
        <p>Click Me</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde explicabo repellat minima magnam totam, temporibus nemo saepe praesentium ipsam a quidem. Mollitia vero impedit architecto quod ex voluptates neque eveniet!
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: ElementRef;
isClicked=false;

play() {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
    this.isClicked=true;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 1):

Since you use angular you can use *ngIf or *ngShow and with a (click) event you can trigger it

```
    <div (click)="showDescription = !showDescription" class="video-banner">
        <video controls>
            <source src="011-video-files.mp4">
        </video>
        <div *ngIf="showDescription" class="banner-description">
            <p>Click Me</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sea this one click me button is working there is jquery for that to work check this I think it's useful for you

```js
document.getElementById("banner-description").addEventListener("click", changeBackground);

// OTHER FUN STUFF WE CAN DO:
    function changeBackground() {
      var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
      document.body.style.background = '#' + randomColor;
    };
```

```css
#banner-description{
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    top : 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: rebeccapurple;
}
.video-banner{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis laudantium nobis laboriosam quaerat. Quo, veritatis harum nemo eligendi sed dicta fugiat ad. Voluptas ea maxime qui nostrum blanditiis facere natus!
    </div>

    <div class="video-banner">
        <video controls>
            <source src="011-video-files.mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="banner-description">
            <p>Click Me</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde explicabo repellat minima magnam totam, temporibus nemo saepe praesentium ipsam a quidem. Mollitia vero impedit architecto quod ex voluptates neque eveniet!
    </div>



</body>
```